# Fibonacci sequence with Unfold in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, fibonacci, unfold

I'm relatively new to Ocaml and think I'm understanding the Unfold function correctly but I just can't see how to make a fibonacci sequence using it. Wouldn't we need to have a holder variable of the last two values so we could find the current one? All help is greatly appreciated. I'm adding the Unfold function below for reference.

```
let rec unfold (f: 'seed -> ('a * 'seed)) (stop : 'b -> bool) (b :'seed) : 'a list =
if stop b then []
else 
  let x, b' = f b in
   x :: (unfold f stop b')
```

Answer (score 2):

You had the right idea of storing the last two values to create the next one. The trick is to store them in a tuple.

The generator function takes the tuple, returns the first number as the generated value and creates a new state with the second number of the tuple and the next fibonacci number:

```
fun (a, b) -> (a, (b, a+b))
```

The stop function just takes the tuple and decides when to stop, e.g.

```
fun (a, b) -> a > 1000
```

The first state is `(0, 1)` which are the first two fibonacci numbers.

**Putting it all together:**

```
# unfold (fun (a, b) -> (a, (b, a+b))) (fun (a, b) -> a > 1000) (0, 1);;
- : int list =
[0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 5; 8; 13; 21; 34; 55; 89; 144; 233; 377; 610; 987]
```

Comment: Thank you / Danke !